# Thymeleaf: How to loop through a list in inverse order?

Tags: html, loops, for-loop, thymeleaf, each

I have a list called 'notifications' and I use Thymeleaf 'each method' to access its elements one by one. I can do this successfully as below.

```
<li th:each="n : *{notifications}"> 
    <h4 type="text" th:text="*{n.message}"></h4>
</li>
```

note: 'message' is the attribute I need to retrieve from the list.

How can I access the elements in the reverse order? For an example if this is my current output,

```
Cat
Dog
Rat
```

How can I get output as this?

```
Rat
Dog
Cat
```

Comment: Reverse the list on the server side, perhaps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would reverse it server side, if possible.  If you don't want to do that, maybe something like this would work for you:

```
<li th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(notifications.size() - 1, 0, -1)}"> 
    <h4 type="text" th:text="${notifications[i].message}"></h4>
</li>
```

Comment: @Shyklar 's answer below is an enhanced version of this which you'd want to use in most circumstances.

Answer (score 4):

If you *already use* 'th:each' I want to complement the **Metroids** answer. It may be useful to declare a local variable. Thus, the inner part of the loop will not require changes.

```
<li th:each="i : ${#numbers.sequence(notifications.size() - 1, 0, -1)}"
     th:with="n=${notifications[i]}"> 
    <h4 type="text" th:text="${n.message}"></h4>
</li>
```

Comment: provide a little explanation maybe? :)

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Comment: The originally selected answer didn't actually set the "n" object within the loop, so everywhere you used it you would have had to switch to "notifications[i]" which would be hard work.  This answer sets the "n" object to that, so that the internal block would be the same as a normal th:each block.